# javascript call declared url as GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, get, global-variables

In my page index.php, I have a script javascript to call my API REST with ajax.
According to the working environment, I call a specific API REST: for developpement environment I call "url_api_dev" et for production environment I call "url_api_prod".

This is my index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    <script src="../js/config.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('resady');
    var configs = config(env);
    var url_api = configs['url_api'];
    var token_api = configs['token_api'];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token_api
        },
        data: {
           ...
        },
        url: url_api ,
        contentType: "json",
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my config.js

```
var env = "prod";
function config(env) {
  if (env == "prod") {
    url = "url_api_prod";
    token_api = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJyb2xl";
  } else {
    url = "utl_api_dev";
    token_api = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJyb2xlcyI6";
 }
 url_api = url + "get-action";
 $result = new Array();
 $result['url_api'] = url_api;
 $result['token_api'] = token_api;
 return $result;
}
```

So My index.php call with ajax

> GET: "url_api_prod/get-action"in production env

OR

> GET: "url_api_dev/get-action" in developpement env.

On the other hand I noticed sometimes the script called the following two api in same time:

> GET: "url_api_prod" AND GET: "url_api_dev"

Why did I encounter this behavior? when we can have this behavior?

Comment: not sure how that would be possible

Comment: It can happen only if `config` is called twice with different `env`. Can you provide a reproducible example? The current examples are not sufficient to figure out what the problem could be.

Comment: In production always 'env = prod' I don't have calls with different env.

Comment: I have the two calls in the same time '2019-02-25 12:51'

Comment: your last comment totally differs from your actual question. be specific what the exact problem is ? 2nd thing your are not putting any slash / in your url . 3rd thing is that the global  variable env declared in your config.js has no meaning , the fucntion config is using the local variable passed to it with the same name env

Comment: 1- I delete to last comment
2- I did not put the real url in my question 3- in index.php I send the global "env" to the function "config"